# YouTrack Workflow reset field value

Tags: youtrack

I have a JavaScript Workflow for YouTrack that, when an issue is set to Open, should reset the several fields to "null". This is the code I am using to accomplish this:

```
Open: {
  onEnter: function (ctx, issue) {
    issue.fields['Alpha Approved By'] = null; // <- This is where the error points
    issue.fields['UAT Approved By'] = null;
    issue.fields['QA Approved By'] = null;
    issue.fields['PM Approved By'] = null;
  },
  transitions: {
    Working: {
      targetState: 'In Progress'
    },
    Rejected: {
      targetState: 'Rejected'
    }
  }
},
```

However, whenever I try to create an issue, I get the following error message:
`TypeError: Cannot read property "fields" from undefined (workflow-enforcement/workflow-enforcement#20)`

Line 20 is marked with a comment in the code snippet

How should I be setting the value of these fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `issue` is a part of a context object (`ctx`), not a parameter. So the code should look like:

`onEnter: function (ctx) {
  var issue = ctx.issue;
  issue.fields['Alpha Approved By'] = null; 
  ...
}`